# failed to query database with filter in django 2.0

Tags: django

I'm developing a blog app with django2.0.

in the models layer, I defined a class `Post`, and defined a attribute `created_time` with `DateTimeField`, then I tried to query the posts based on the created_time with two arguments `year` and `month`, but finally it turns out there is no object got from the query.

What seems to be the problem?

1.blog/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    created_time = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

2.blog/views.py

```
def archives(request, year, month):
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(created_time__year=year,
                                    created_time__month=month).
                                     order_by('-created_time')
    print('Year:{0}.\nMonth:{1}'.format(year,month))

    count = 0
    for a in post_list:
        count += 1
    print("I've found {} post here!".format(str(count)))

    return render(request, 
                  'blog/index.html', 
                   context={'post_list': post_list})
```

3.blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
...
url(r'^archives/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})/$',views.archives,name='archives'),
```

]

4. templates/blog.index.html

`<li><a href="{% url 'blog:archives' date.year date.month %}">{{date.year}}年{{date.month}}月</a></li>`

In the database I've added lots of post, but finally the console output is like:
[image]

**Why******?

Note that, if I remove one argument `created_time__month=month` in view `archives()` as below, it can get the correct query results.

```
def archives(request, year, month):
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(created_time__year=year).order_by('-created_time')
```

[image]

And below is the database info:

[image]

Comment: when you remove month from filter you only filter by year and get not valid print info and data.

Comment: But no matter I filter with only `year` or both of them, it should return the valid info and data, and the results should be the same according to the current database. right?

Answer (score 1):

First, you may convert `year` and `month` url argument to `int`, to ensure the filtering is done correctly. By default, you receive these values as `str`.

```
def archives(request, year, month):
    year, month = int(year), int(month)
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(created_time__year=year,
                                    created_time__month=month).
                                     order_by('-created_time')
    # [...]
```

Then, don't use a loop to count number of results of a queryset. Use `count()`:

```
print("I've found {} post here!".format(post_list.count()))
```

In addition, if you need to understand why this particular queryset returns nothing when this other returns some results, you could check the underlying SQL query generated by Django. This should help to determine where the problem comes from:

```
print(post_list.query)
```

In addition, as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#year), Django may convert your date values into current timezone (depending on `settings.USE_TZ`) before executing the SQL request. That could explain this kind of error sometimes.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot for the thorough explanation and guide.

Comment: sorry, Antwane, I made a wrong testing, in fact it didn't work since it's not the `int` resulting to this problem, instead it's caused by MYSQL. as you mentioned I query again with the printed SQL request, it can get nothing from mysql with `select convert_tz('2017-09-19 17:30:00', 'UTC', 'Asia/Shanghai');` but if I execute the cmd `select convert_tz('2017-09-19 17:30:00', '+00:00', '+08:00');` there is the result. So the solution is try to fix the MYSQL problem

Comment: MySQL: load the time zone tables with ![mysql_tzinfo_to_sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#database-time-zone-definitions)